# Scanning CSV file for specific value

Tags: python, csv

I'm attempting to use Python to scan a CSV file and find a specific value in that file. I'm encountering problems with my program printing that the value isn't in the file when it is there. Any help is appreciated.

```
with open("sun_data.csv") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    csvInfo = list(readCSV)
print(csvInfo)

x = int(input("Enter a time: "))

found = False
for i in range(len(csvInfo)):
    if csvInfo[i] == x:
        found = True
        print(str(x) + " was found in the database.")
        break 

if not found:
    print("I'm sorry, " + str(x) + " was not found in the database.")
```

Comment: `x` is an `int`, `csvInfo[i]` is a `str`.

Comment: Are the values read from the CSV as integers (as you assume here) or as strings?

Comment: String. The content in csvInfo looks as is: [['Date', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'March ', 'April', 'May'], ['1', '273', '93', '59', '266', '128'], ['2', '41', '110', '315', '43', '263'], ['3', '78', '649', '620', '538', '700'], ['18', '90', '635', '600', '519', '450'], ['19', '7', '634', '558', '517', '449']]

Answer (score 1):

Your code with an int cast in the comparison

````
with open("sun_data.csv") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    csvInfo = list(readCSV)
print(csvInfo)

x = int(input("Enter a time: "))

found = False
for i in range(len(csvInfo)):
    if int(csvInfo[i]) == x:
        found = True
        print(str(x) + " was found in the database.")
        break 

if not found:
    print("I'm sorry, " + str(x) + " was not found in the database.")
    ```
````